# Send email with a PDF embedded

Tags: php, wp-mail

I am trying to send an email with a PDF embedded in the body of the email. The email gets sent, but the PDF doesn't show up. If I view the source of the email, the code does show the embedded PDF, but it's not showing in the email. I also tried sending the PDF as an attachment. Again, the email sends, but the attachment doesn't. My code is below.

```
$filename = $sql->filename;
$newlink = get_home_url() . "/wp-content/uploads/communitybb_events/files/$lastid/";
$fulllink = $newlink . $filename;

$message = "<h2>" . $title . "</h2>";
$message = $message . "<b>Date/Time: </b>" . $newdate . " at " . $newtime . "<br><br>";
$message = $message . "<embed src='$fulllink' width='1000' height='1000'>";

$to = $user->user_email;
$subject = "New Event Posted";
$attachments = array($fulllink);
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
    'From: Community Bulletin Board <communitybb@email.com>'
);

$success = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);
if (!$success) {
    $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
    error_log($errorMessage);
} else {
    error_log("email has been successfully sent to user whose email is " . $to);
}
```

Comment: are you sure the email client at the other end supports embed tags? Embedding a PDF directly into an email using HTML like that is _highly_ unusual, I'm surprised it would work, it sounds like something I'd want to strip out for security if I ran a mail service. Note to clarify that the attachments array expects file paths, not URLs, and the way that URL is constructed is very unusual, would it not be better to use something like  `site_url( '/wp-content/...' )` or `home_url( '/wp-content/...' )`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have thought about the security for embedding files into email. That's probably the issue.